# ResNet - NaN during classification (not training) on same dataset used for validation

Tags: machine-learning, nan, caffe

Some very quick background:

Training on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with latest Caffe branch on GTX 1080

Classification on OSX

I'm wondering if anyone can shed light on this issue. I'm finetuning ResNet-50 using caffe from [here](https://github.com/cvjena/cnn-models). I'm experimenting with a small dataset. For training, I have approximately 1248 images and for validation, I have 1656. I am going through the entire validation set each time I test during training.

Now, during training, I am not seeing any NaNs or anything that would indicate gradient blow up or something like that. No NaNs, infs, or anything strange. When I load the net and try to classify the **same images** used for validation during training, NaNs show up. Any idea why this is? Could it be the difference between the GPU architecture vs the CPU architecture in carrying out the calculations in training vs classification?

[EDIT: I'm not doing any preprocessing]

[EDIT2: It seems stochastic. If I run the same image through again, the network will properly output a probability or it will output NaN again. My solution currently is to run the same image through the network until a non-NaN shows up, but sometimes, this takes awhile]

Comment: there is an issue with BatchNorm layer that might result with nans. I would suggest looking into it.

Comment: Could you clarify or provide any additional details? And maybe I'm misunderstanding how Caffe works. When running the test iterations, I'm never seeing any nans in the testing loss or test accuracies. Wouldn't any issues with BatchNorm layers show up here as well?

Comment: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5136

Comment: I looked at the PR. It looks like the opposite problem of what I'm having, no? It appears the problem there is that training on GPU produces NaNs, but CPU works fine. For me, training on GPU seems to be fine, but running on a CPU produces NaNs...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe different type of preprocessing. You get NaN output for NaN input. Therefore if you somehow divide by 0 with your preprocessing (Normalization?) this can occur.

Comment: Good thought - forgot to mention. There is no pre-processing when I train or when I run the classification.